# Re render content in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, angularjs, django

I am using angular for front end and Python-Django as backend . I am rendering an HTML in python using `TemplateResponse()` and this response is then sent to angular as response where I store this in some `$scope variable` . The important thing here is The HTML I am rendering in PYthon includes Css, Js , HTML + Angular code . e.g.,

```
<div  ng-repeat='val in values'> 
  <span>{{ val }}</span>
</div>
```

Now Python will render this code (includes much more but this a sample) and send response to angular (I'll also send this values data from python )where I'll store this in $scope.

```
$scope.html_response = response sent from Python
$scope.values = values data from python  (it will be a object so angular can loop over this easily )
```

I have everything in angular HTMl + Angular Scope which is used in HTML . 
Now The main thing is how to bind them together so that HTML gets angular scope and loop over the data. For this I am using angular directive .

**HTML :**

```
<div dynamic="html_response"></div>
```

**Angular directive :**

```
app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This directive is doing binding of angular scope with HTML for me .

Everything was working for me until I got one issue . AS I explained above I am rendering HTML first then binding angular scope. But In one of my case (a js slider) I need to render angular first then render HTML (js code) means slider js must render after angular so that slider can already have data available to show .

But I can't render angular data from python side first . I have to send HTML response to angular whatever it includes .

Is their any other approach or something I can do at angular end so that I can solve my issue .

Comment: When you print `{{ val }}` is the value from angular or django?

Comment: @Gocht Its angular , I know both hv same syntex and thats by I have changed angular syntex . I am actually using this syntex `{$ val $}` but heree I have written `{{ val }}` so that angular dev do not get confused that I am using wrong syntex.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is to separate the HTML/CSS/JS rendering from the data itself.

You can achieve this by first generating the HTML/CSS/JS in Python and have Angular then fetch the data (in JSON format?) needed for the JS slider from the Django backend and render it. This means you would have 2 accesses to the backend - one for the page itself and the other for the data required by the page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . I'll surely look into this approach